# How to float elements left or right of a horizontally centered element?

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment

For the pagination I'd like to use a horizontal alignment of elements looking like this:

```
|<first page> | <previous page> | page X of N | <next page> | <last page>|
```

The element `page X of N` should always stay in the middle of the whole line, **even if one of the other elements is missing**. E.g.

```
|<first page> | <previous page> | page N of N                            |
```

The floating elements should always be attached directly to the element in the centre.

My approach looks like this (last row of a search results table):

```
<tr colspan="4"><td class="pager">
    <ul style="margin:0;">
        <li style="display:inline-block; float:left;">  outer left  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block; float:left;">  inner left  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block; float:none; text-align:center; position:absolute; left:50%; width:100px; margin-left:-50px;">  always centred  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block; float:right;">  outer right  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block; float:right;">  inner right  </li>
    </ul>
</td></tr>
```

But the result looks like this, i.e. the floating elements are not "attached" to the centred element:

```
|<first page> | <previous page> |          page X of N            | <next page> | <last page>|
|<-- (left border)                                                         (right border) -->|
```

Comment: Hmm... i guess i have to solve this with a table and thee columns. Can tables be nested?

Comment: HTML tables can be nested as deeply as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another, quite simple solution:
Centre everything and just hide the elements as required: `visibility: hidden`:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="visibility: hidden;">  outer left  </span>
    <span>  inner left  </span>
    always centred
    <span>  inner right  </span>
    <span>  outer right  </span>
</div>
```

This results in:

```
|               <inner left> always centred <inner right> <outer right>   |
| <- left border                      |                   right border -> |
|                                   centre                                |
```

Answer (score 4):

### HTML table

Basically, use a table with 3 columns. Add a fixed-width wrapper to the left and right columns, aligned towards the middle column.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/yvRjR/1/)

The demo shows a variety of pagination bars, with balanced and unbalanced links to the left and right of the `page X of N` link. To make it a little more obvious what's happening, background colors have been added to different elements.

**Key points:**

- Use a table with 3 columns. Give the middle column a small fixed width, and don't specify a width for the left and right columns. The middle column will expand as needed to fit its content, and any leftover space will be split evenly between the left and right columns.
- Add a wrapper element inside the left and right columns. Give the wrapper a fixed width that's large enough to fit the largest amount of content it would ever have (but that will also fit within the smallest screen size supported). The wrappers must have the same width, or the middle column won't be centered.
- Align the left column to the right, and the right column to left (so both are aligned towards the middle).
- Align the contents of the left wrapper to the right, and the right wrapper to the left (so the contents of both are aligned towards the middle).
- Place the centered `page X of N` link in the middle column.
- Place any links that appear to the left of `page X of N` in the left-column content wrapper, and likewise place any links that appear to the right in the right-column content wrapper.

**HTML**

```
<table class="pagination">
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">
            <div class="content">
                <span>left</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="column2">
            <span>centered</span>
        </td>
        <td class="column3">
            <div class="content">
                <span>right</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.pagination {
    width: 100%;
}

.pagination .column1 {
    text-align: right;
}
.pagination .column2 {
    width: 1px;
}
.pagination .column3 {
    text-align: left;
}

.pagination .content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
.pagination .column1 .content {
    text-align: right;
}
.pagination .column3 .content {
    text-align: left;
}

.pagination span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements are not attached to the centered element because you are floating them to left/right border. As much as I understood, in order to achieve what you want, you should lose the float and center the whole `ul`.

Comment: Not the whole thing should be centred. Only one element. The remaining elements should be attached to the sides. If there are elements on the right side only, the centred part should still stay in the middle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. I tried the code above on my machine and it works fine. Make sure that some other CSS doesn't mess up formatting.

Comment: I think you don't ;) If you centre four elements, which one is in the centre..? Try to centre the second sample: `<first page> | <previous page> | page N of N` - page N of N should be in the middle of the <ul>

Answer (score 0):

Don't float anything, just set the outer/parent element to `text-align: center`

like this:

```
<ul style="margin:0;  text-align:center;">
        <li style="display:inline-block;">  outer left  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;">  inner left  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;">  always centred  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;">  outer right  </li>
        <li style="display:inline-block;">  inner right  </li>
    </ul>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LMZsL/

Comment: This only works when all elements are present. As soon as one element is removed, the centred part is not in the centre any more...

Answer (score 0):

try position:absolute for col1, 2, 4 and 5 with left and right % ?